# Drupal 7- "Users who bought this also bought that" module

Tags: 7, ubercart

Does anyone know of a module for Drupal 7 that provides a "users who bought this also bought that" feature?

I found [Ubercart Views](http://drupal.org/project/uc_views) but it only works for D6, not D7.

My site uses Drupal 7 and Ubercart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, a module that does the same for you: [Recommender API](https://www.drupal.org/project/recommender).

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides a set of easy-to-use, fully-documented APIs and computational tools to help you write Drupal content recommendation sub-modules.
>
> Modules built with Recommender API
>
> - Browsing History Recommender: "Users who browsed this node also browsed"; personalized node recommendation based on users' browsing history.
> - Commerce Recommender: Personalized products recommendations based on customers purchasing history.
> - OG Similar groups module: "Users who joined this group also joined"
> - Ubercart Products Recommender: "Customers who ordered this also ordered" and personalized recommendation "Recommended for you"
> - Fivestar Recommender: User-to-user and Item-to-item (used in Amazon.com) recommendations for Fivestar module.
> - Points Voting Recommender: User-to-user and Item-to-item (used in Amazon.com) recommendations for Up/Down and Plus 1 modules.
> - Flag Recommender: Recommender for the Flag module.

Answer (score 1):

There are two modules available for Ubercart; the first one is [Ubercart Products Recommender](http://drupal.org/project/uc_rec) which provides a View for:

> Users who ordered this product also ordered.

The second is [easyrec for ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/easyrec_for_ubercart), which provides a block called:

> other users also bought

Either one should be fine for what you want, and both have a stable Drupal 7 version available.